# Using reflect, how to check if an embedding type overrides a method of the embedded type?

Tags: go, go-reflect

With embedded types, how can I distinguish using package reflect if a type is implementing a given interface through the embedded type or if it has its own implementation of the method that overrides the implementation of the embedded type?

Concrete example ([full example on play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/IeLrxpaBpts)):

```golang
type A string

func (a A) String() string {
    return string(a)
}

type A1 struct {
    A
}

type A2 struct {
    A
}

func (a A2) String() string {
    return strings.ReplaceAll(string(a.A), " ", "_")
}

var (
    a1 A1
    a2 A2
)
```

When inspecting `a1` and `a2` using `reflect`, how can I tell that the implementation of method `String` in `A1` is inherited while method `String` in `A2` is directly attached to `A2`?

I tried to compare `reflect.TypeOf(a1).MethodByName("String").Func` with `reflect.TypeOf(a1).Field(0).Type.MethodByName("String").Func` but the two values are different.

Note: my real use case is that I want to write unit tests that enforce that if A implements json.Marshaler, a type embedding A has its own implementation of json.Marshaler.

Comment: You may need to examine the source code determine where the method is declared. The go/ast package will be useful for that. Replace "inherited" with "promoted" to avoid the *Go does not have inheritance* downvotes.

Comment: It also doesn't have overrides. I'm curious though *why* you need this information at runtime, because needing to know this implies a fundamental design flaw in the first place, and a likely XY Problem.

Comment: this does not sound like something for a unit test -- it sounds like static analysis, just like all the analyses already done by go vet

Comment: A unit test probably should test that unmarshaling works correct and shouldn’t be bothered how or why it is correct.

Comment: @JimB Fair, but I am familiar with the reflect API, not with [go/types](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/). I want to know if I'm in an area of typing information which is not available at all through reflect.